# Runtime allocation of OnTAP event Delphi Seattle

Tags: delphi, events, runtime, delphi-10-seattle

I am using **Firemonkey** and
I would like to allocate the **OnTap Event to an object at Runtime.**

The code that i have tries is basically the same as the one i use for the **OnClick event:**

Header at the top :

```
procedure txtHostClick(Sender: TObject);
```

Procedure :

```
procedure TMyForm.txtHostClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   //do stuff
end;
```

Assignment to event handler:

```
hotspot :=  Tmemo.Create(Highlight_Scrollbox);
hotspot.OnClick := txtHostClick;
```

So i try to apply the same logic to the **OnTap event** and it gives the following error :

**[DCC Error] s3.pas(4338): E2009 Incompatible types: 'Parameter lists differ'**

Below is a code sample of what I have tried:

Header at the top :

```
procedure txtOnTAPEvent(Sender: TObject; const [Ref] Point: TPointF);
```

Procedure :

```
procedure TMyForm.txtOnTAPEvent(Sender: TObject; const [Ref] Point: TPointF);
begin
   //do stuff
end;
```

Assignment to event handler:

```
hotspot :=  Tmemo.Create(Highlight_Scrollbox);
hotspot.OnTap := txtOnTAPEvent;
```

There is gap in my knowledge that needs to be filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `[Ref]` attribute from the `Point` parameter:

```
procedure txtOnTAPEvent(Sender: TObject; const Point: TPointF);
```

```
procedure TMyForm.txtOnTAPEvent(Sender: TObject; const Point: TPointF);
begin
    //do stuff
end;
```

If you double-click on any UI control's `OnTap` event in the Object Inspector at design-time, you will see that the IDE generates an `OnTap` event handler that does not include the `[Ref]` attribute.  This is further enforced by the fact that there is no `[Ref]` attribute in the declaration of `FMX.Types.TTapEvent` to begin with:

```
TTapEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; const Point: TPointF) of object;
```

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for the answer. It is correct. I was also wondering if you could explain the following. When i drop an object on the form and create an OnTap event using the built in events tab on the IDE, The procedure that is created has the [Ref] field?

Comment: I tested the IDE before posting my answer. Using Seattle Update 1, when I had the IDE create the event, no `[Ref]` attribute was present.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept this. I don't have update 1 so it might just be in the version without the update.